# Xcode error when importing Facebook sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk

I am trying to build an iOS application in Xcode. I have imported Facebook SDK in Unity 3D then build the client. However, Facebook SDK libraries don't seem to be read in Xcode. I am sure that required frameworks were properly imported. What could be the solution to this?

Also, I've followed this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/ios

[FB SDK error in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5etmf.png) (screenshot)

Comment: try to download and add fresh fb sdk.

Comment: i downloaded a new fb sdk adn reimported it to xcode. still not working :// i get the same errors..

Comment: Which version of the FB Unity SDK are you using? Does it reproduce with any sample project?